# see all records in Subgrid Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, microsoft-dynamics

when i click on the button "see all records" in Subgrid i get this error:

[image: see all records]

[image: Error]

Comment: Is this happening in any particular record, particular entity subgrid, or all ?

Comment: hey @ArunVinoth it is happening in all entity subgrid

Comment: Whats your version? Im not seeing this issue. If this started happening after weekly update or something you may need a MS ticket